# Three.js - Trying to load multiple material objects

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, data-visualization

I am working with three.js and I am trying to load multiple material objects. When I run the code, the first material object maps to the data properly. Once it rotates, the second material object then populates unexpectedly. Ideally I would like the first material object [cubeMaterial] to read in data[0] which is 49 and the second material object [cubeMaterialTwo] to read in data[1] which is 7.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.3/build/three.js"></script>

let scene, camera, renderer;

let cubeGroup;

init();
animate();

function init() {

const data = [
[49, 7]
]

var i = 1;

width = 500
height = 500
fov = 9
aspect = 1/5
near = .1
far = 1000

loader = new THREE.TextureLoader()

scene = new THREE.Scene(); // ADDED

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
camera.position.set(50, 30, 50);
camera.lookAt( scene.position );


cubeGeometries = data.map(row => {
 return row.map(c => {
  return new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(0.2, c / 8, 0.2);
 })
})

var materialArray = [];

const cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
 map: loader.load('../path/to/.jpgOne')
});
cubeMaterial.color.convertSRGBToLinear();

const cubeMaterialTwo = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
map: loader.load('../path/to/.jpgTwo')
});
cubeMaterialTwo.color.convertSRGBToLinear();

materialArray.push(cubeMaterial, cubeMaterialTwo);

const cubeMeshes = cubeGeometries.map(row => {
  return row.map(cubeGeometry => new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, materialArray))
})

cubeGroup = new THREE.Group();
 data.forEach((row, i, iarr) => {
  row.forEach((d, j, jarr) => {
   cubeMeshes[i][j].position.set(
    i / iarr.length - 0.5,
    d / 8 * 0.5 - 0.6,
    j / jarr.length - 0.5);

   //cubeMeshes[i][j].scale.set(1,4,1);
   cubeGroup.add(cubeMeshes[i][j]);
  })
 })

const mainLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 5.0);
 mainLight.position.set(10, 10, 10);

const ambientLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xddeeff, 0x202020, 3);

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
 color: 0x0000ff
});

scene.add(cubeGroup);
scene.add(mainLight);
scene.add(ambientLight);


renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement); 

}

function animate() {
 requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 cubeGroup.rotation.y += 0.005;
 renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

Comment: Just reading quickly your code, you are using a single variable for the loader(which is asynchronous) in a synchronous pattern. I would recommend to create a new instance of `TextureLoader` just to check that’s the issue

Comment: @jscastro thanks for the comment. unfortunately still same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code with a minimum tweak, and it's loading both textures, but you are using them in the opposite sides of the meshes as you are passing the full `materialArray` to the Mesh constructor.
I have created a [fiddle loading two textures](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/uwasftym/24/) with your code to repro the issue, but it loads both.

```
  const cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://i.postimg.cc/25m7H09s/metal1.jpg')
  });
  cubeMaterial.color.convertSRGBToLinear();

  const cubeMaterialTwo = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://i.postimg.cc/pXs9NqTN/OIP.jpg')
  });
  cubeMaterialTwo.color.convertSRGBToLinear();
```

Not sure if that's what you were trying to achieve or loading two meshes each one with a texture, but definitely the `TextureLoader` is loading both textures.
[image]
[image]

If this answer is solving your initial question, please mark it as "answer accepted", this way will also help other users to know it was the right solution to the problem.

**EDIT:** I have modified the [fiddle loading two textures](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/uwasftym/24/) now with a random for each object... you can try it many times and you'll see it works.

```
  return row.map(cubeGeometry => new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, materialArray[Math.round(Math.random())]))
  })
```

[image]

**EDIT 2**: I found the solution to your last issue, as said you need an iterator and each block will have a different texture. Here you have the [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/uwasftym/37/), and the relevant code is just these lines to replace the original.

```
  let index = 0;
  const cubeMeshes = cubeGeometries.map((row) => {
    index++;
    return row.map((cubeGeometry, index) => new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, materialArray[index]))
  })
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time out of your day to assist me with this problem. Unfortunately this doesn't fix the issue I am having. What I am trying to do is not flip the objects so, for example, the taller block has one texture on one side, and then when it rotates, it flips to the other texture. What I am trying to achieve is that the taller block is one texture (material) for the entirety of the function (both sides) while the other block (smaller one) is also the other texture for the entirety of the function. My apologies if I didn't make that clearer.

Comment: That issue is because you are passing the full `materialArray` to the mesh constructor, if you want that you have to use a random on the `materialArray` positions...

Comment: Edited my answer and the fiddle... just try it in the answer link. you have to run it a few times as it's a random 0-1 and many times could be the same index returned..

Comment: I have marked the answer as accepted as it answers my original question. Having said that, what I am really trying to do (which I should have been more clear about originally) is attach the data object to each material so that it isn't random. The tall bar is always one texture, the small bar is always the other. Is this possible ?

Comment: Then you need an iterator variable through the materialArray items, as you use in your code below when you go through the data.forEach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218781/discussion-between-jscastro-and-bullybear17).